# SynchronizationContext - strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

```
public static void Init()
{
    //var task = GetSource1();
    //var task = GetSource2();
    //var task = GetSource3();
    var task = MyClient();
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result);
}

private static async Task<string> GetSource1()
{
    var sourceTask = WebClient();
    sourceTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await sourceTask;
}

private static async Task<string> GetSource2()
{
    var sourceTask = MyClient();
    sourceTask.ConfigureAwait(true);
    return await sourceTask;
}

private static async Task<string> GetSource3()
{
    var sourceTask = MyClient();
    sourceTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await sourceTask;
}

private static async Task<string> WebClient()
{
    return await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://4pda.ru").ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static Task<string> MyClient()
{
    var t = new Task<string>(() => new WebClient().DownloadString("http://4pda.ru"));
    t.ConfigureAwait(false);
    t.Start();
    return t;
}
```

This code works fine. I get the source in `MessageBox`. However why I get deadlock when I use `var task = GetSource3()`? I thought that it must works because I use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and avoid the context switching

Comment: You should be avoiding the deadlock by *doing everything asynchronously* not by pushing continuations to thread pool threads.

Comment: You should almost never use the Task constructor. If you want to offload work to a ThreadPool thread use `Task.Run`

Comment: It was test sample. I got answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait` is a pure method. It returns a value but has no effect on its own. It returns a customized awaitable (`ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`) that you need to await:

```
await task.ConfigureAwait();
```

However, this isn't how you should handle deadlocks. It's a precaution but you should avoid blocking on asynchronous code to begin with.

Comment: In other words: It's configure *await*, not configure *task*.